# Micro-Services: How to avoid repeated polling of the same event from Kafka

Tags: microservices, apache-kafka

I have an Micro-services where we get the event messages from a Kafka messaging system. The event message contains the  orders information, quantity, the mode of package and delivery location. At a predetermined time, these events are pushed to the Kafka stream. A special event ***full delivery*** event is issued to signify that all events have been sent from the producer. The MS on receiving the ***full delivery*** event stops processing the events going forward.

This worked fine until now as

1. We have limited number of events around 150.
2. Kafka and Micro-services were a single instance and was run on a single machine.

When we use multiple Kafka nodes, a huge amount of events (10,000, for instance), and numerous Micro-services. In those cases, I believe it will lead to error.

How do I avoid,

1. How to prevent selecting the same event twice.
2. What if ***full delivery***  event is picked first but there are still a lot of other events that need to be picked up?

What changes should I make to the system to prevent these scenarios?

**Update**

*What is the benefit of explicitly adding an ending event and stopping processing*

Let us suppose there are two delivery teams (Team1 and Team2). Team1 serves Postal Codes 10243 and 10245, while Team2 serves Postal Codes 10247 and 10249.
Now, there is a Sony TV package that needs to be delivered at Postal-Code: 10243, so this falls under Team1's jurisdiction. However, they only have this one order. T the neighbouring locations 10247 and 10249, which fall under Team2, have 30 orders to deliver. In such cases, the package delivery can be given to Team2. Saving money this way. There is a large minimum amount that must be paid for each Team in order for items to be delivered. These are business decisions over which we have no control.

To deal with such a scenario, we used the logic described above.

Comment: What is the benefit of explicitly adding an ending event and stopping processing, as opposed to not popping more events on and therefore not processing these non-existing events?

Comment: @Flater, I have updated the question, Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Event handlers should be idempotent. It should not matter if the same event is handled multiple times. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: @RikD, That wont help in solving the underlying problem. Consider the above example which I have described in the update section. Let us assume in the absence of full delivery event, the processing commence the moment  it starts receiving the events in that case the above logic will not yield the same result.

Comment: @User27854 The delivery example is a bit counterproductive. First you define teams as being responsible for a specific area, and then you try to override that by finding a solution that goes against your own definition. The challenge is one you imposed on yourself. The obvious first solution is to stop doing so. Furthermore, it doesn't quite answer my question. What is this "end of delivery" event doing/causing?

Comment: @Flater, To clear things up,The events are only sent out once per day. The end of delivery event signifies that all the events are send and there are no more events which will be  coming in and the processing of events can begin.